# "the problem is + v-ing" vs "the problem is + bare infinitives" vs "the problem is + to-infinitives"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, predicative-complement

A: What is the problem?

1. B: The problem is making sure that everything works fine.
2. B: The problem is to make sure that everything works fine.
3. B: The problem is make sure that everything works fine.

Which one is correct?

If two or three of them are correct, what is the difference between them?

I checked ngram. It shows that the structure "the problem is + to-infinitives" is used by far more than two others. So I guess it is correct. But the other two structures are also used:

[link1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20problem%20is%20to%20do%2Cthe%20problem%20is%20do%2Cthe%20problem%20is%20doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
[image]
[link2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20problem%20is%20to%20make%2Cthe%20problem%20is%20make%2Cthe%20problem%20is%20making&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
[image]

Comment: One of the reasons for closing questions is to ask which is correct and show no effort at dealing with it.

Comment: Note that, when using Google Ngrams, it is important to look at actual instances to check that they really are what you are looking for. If you look at actual instances of "the problem is do", you will find that they all contain an unwanted full stop or colon, for example: "Ask what they think the problem is. Do not prejudge an answer. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a linking verb ("is") that connects a subject ("the problem") with a predicative expression (in this case, a nominal phrase). It is quite rare for a bare infinitive ("make") to function as any kind of nominal. However, gerunds ("making") and full infinitives ("to make") often function that way, so either of those could head the predicative expression. Thus, sentences 1 and 2 are fine, while 3 is incorrect.

There is no difference in meaning between sentences 1 and 2. Just be aware that gerunds and infinitives aren't grammatically identical, so in other contexts there might be a difference. (If you've researched the issue but still have questions about the differences, then you should ask a new question about that.)